# How to remove disabled property from radio button with select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<script type='text/javascript' href='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.selects').change(function(){
  $('.select').
 })
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype HTML>

<input type='radio' id ='index1' value='1' name='radio1' disabled>radio button 1</input><br><br>
<select class='select' data-value='1'> 
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
</select><br><br>

<input type='radio' id ='index2' value='2' name='radio2' disabled>radio button 2</input><br><br>
<select class='select' data-value='2'> 
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
</select><br><br>
```

How do I remove the disabled property from radio button when select menu changes?

```
<!doctype HTML>

<?php
$x = 1;
$y = 1;
while($x <= 2){
        echo "<input type='radio' id ='index$x' value='$x' name='radio$x' disabled>radio button $x</input><br><br>";
        echo "<select class='select' data-value='$x'>"; 
    while($y<= 4){  
        echo "<option>$y</option>";
        $y++;
    }
    echo "</select><br><br>";
    $x++;
    $y = 1; 
}
?>

<script type='text/javascript' href='jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').change(function(){
        var sel = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var selVal = $(this).val();
            if(selVal >= 3){
                $('#index'+sel).prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When the select menu option value reaches 3 or above value, the disabled property from radio button will change to false. I have also tried this script below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').change(function(){
        var sel = $(this).attr('data-value');
        if($( ".select option:selected" ) >= 3){
            $('#index'+sel).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I saw a typographical error in my code in `href='jquery-2.1.4.min/js'` . I tried replacing it but still doesn't work.I received a console error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in line 6 which is `$(document).ready(function(){`

EDITED: provided Stack snippet converted to html

Comment: Please provide output HTML, rather than PHP source. It makes mockups so much easier to create. I hate mentally compiling PHP :)

Comment: I dont understand your problem. It seems that your first codeblock is doing exactly what you want (changing the disabled property of its radio btn), what is the problem?

Comment: yes your code is running good . what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I'm running my code but it doesn't seem to work. I have to set disabled property to false when the option value is `>= 3`

Comment: the reason I placed it inside a while loop, because in my actual code, i'm going to use `while` to output database contents with `while` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: make sure jQuery is working (correctly linked). Are you getting any errors on your console?

Comment: `$( ".select option:selected" )` will not work. If you plan to use that, you will need to use `$(this)` to get the currently selected `select` info as there are multiple `selects`

Comment: Again: Please provide output HTML of your page to allow the creation of a mockup. I missed the multiple selects due to the &%^$ PHP :)

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with your actual issue. Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: That HTML helped (a lot). New answer added below. Hopefully I got it right this time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prop('disabled')` can take a boolean expression resulting in `true` or  `false`, which will disable or enable the control.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select').change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $('#index' + sel).prop('disabled', selVal < 3);
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wnLfxhLo/1/

Note: As the radio state for the default entry should be disabled, you need to fire initial change events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select').change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $('#index' + sel).prop('disabled', selVal < 3);
  }).change();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wnLfxhLo/2/

Comment: You got the closest one mate :) however it only changes disabled prop when it has selected 2, when I select other numbers it turns back to disabled. I'll try to see what seems to be the problem here. I guess it should be easy. Thanks btw

Comment: @chemical_elii: It disables on `1` or `2`, but I was having trouble understanding the question. I see it needs an initial update too, as you do not start in the disabled state. Added a `change()` call to the answer.